# apache2: log requests from LAN to separate logfile

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, configuration, log-files

I would like to separate apache 2.2 log entries in 2 log files: requests from LAN (192.168.0.0/16) should go in a `lan-access.log`, and the rest in the default `access.log`

How can I achieve that? I've tried to use `SetEnvIf` and conditional logging as described in https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html#conditional :

```
$ cat /etc/apache2/conf.d/lan-access-log.conf 
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "192\.168\." fromlan
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/lan-access.log common env=fromlan
```

but it doesn't work and LAN requests keep popping up in the main `acess.log`. What is wrong with my config?

Comment: See also [Disabling Apache logging of particular requests](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/707/Disabling_Apache_logging_of_particular_requests)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to configure the inverse , besides writing your LAN requests to it's own log you need to exclude them from the regular log as well...

```
 # Where your access log is defined
 CustomLog logs/access_log common env=!fromlan
```

Make sure that the SetEnvIf line is declared before the regular access log is.

Comment: Right, added this to `lan-access-log.conf` and it works. I also had to remove the `CustomLog` directive from the virtualhost in `sites-available` or it would override the config.